# How do I only display the contents that is relative to the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

so what i'm trying to do is hide the 2nd image and information when the 1st image is clicked I have already used the .toggle and set the CSS hidden style property however if you click on both of the images then it will display both however when clicking on the 1st image I would like to hide the information and image regrading the second image and when clicking on the second image only show the information relative to the second image

ps sorry if my question is a bit vague if you click on both images in jsfiddle and then click on the 1st image you'll get an idea of what I mean. i'm also a newbie to javascript and jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/dc234561/2rAc5/

HTML code

```
 <img name="MP" id="mp"  src="img/gorillaz-plasticbeach.jpg" data-artist="Gorillaz" data-album="Plastic Beach" alt=""/>
                <img src="img/kingsofleon-comearoundsunshine.jpg" id="mp2" data-artist="Kings Of Leon" data-album="Come Around Sunshine"/>


 <div class="content-1"> 
                 <h2>About us</h2>

    <img id="loadingImage" src="img/brunomars-doowopsandhooligans.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="display:none"/>
    <img id="loadingImage2" src="img/ironmaiden-thefinalfrontier.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="display:none"/>


               <p style="display:none" id="p1">....</p> 

                        <p style="display:none" id="p2">...1 </p>
```

javascript/Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mp").click(function () {
        $("#loadingImage").toggle("slow");
        $( "#p1" ).toggle( "slow" );
    });
})
$("#mp2").click(function () {
        $("#loadingImage2").toggle("slow");
        $( "#p2" ).toggle( "slow" );
        });
```

Comment: May be you can use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/). Sorry couldn't read yourwhole question. It appears to be long.

Comment: sorry  for that thanks for the comment I didn't really know how to phrase the question. also how could I incorporate this into the code would I need to say something like .css.sibling(#loadimages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more efficient way to set it up but you can just verify the visibility of the other image and paragraph elements on click and toggle them if they're visible.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mp").click(function () {
        $("#loadingImage").toggle("slow");
        $( "#p1" ).toggle( "slow" );
        if ($("#loadingImage2").is(":visible")) {
            $("#loadingImage2").toggle("slow");
            $( "#p2" ).toggle( "slow" );
        }
    });
})
```

For simplicity you could make a function that takes care of the toggling so you're writing less repetitive code.

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/Ksbv4/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Make sure all your images that you're clicking on have an ID
        // that starts with loadingImage_ and then a unique number
        $("[id^='loadingImage_']").click(function () {
            // Onclick call your function and pass the id of the element clicked
            toggleLoading($(this).attr("id"));
        })
        function toggleLoading(id) {
            // If this id's matching class is already visible don't do anything
            if (!$("." + id).is(":visible")) {
                // If it isn't, insure that all the elements are hidden
                $("[class*=loadingImage_]").hide();
                // Toggle the elements whose class matches the id of the one clicked.
                $("." + id).toggle("slow");
            }
        }
    });
```

Modified HTML:

```
<img id="loadingImage_1" src="img/gorillaz-plasticbeach.jpg" data-artist="Gorillaz" data-album="Plastic Beach"/>
<img id="loadingImage_2" src="img/kingsofleon-comearoundsunshine.jpg" data-artist="Kings Of Leon" data-album="Come Around Sunshine"/>

<h2>About us</h2>

<img class="loadingImage_1" src="img/brunomars-doowopsandhooligans.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="display:none"/>
<img class="loadingImage_2" src="img/ironmaiden-thefinalfrontier.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="display:none"/>


<p style="display:none" class="loadingImage_1">....</p>
<p style="display:none" class="loadingImage_2">...1</p>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/23aj9/2/

Comment: so like a var = toggle sort of thing? also the code seems to work for the 1st image and not the second in jsfiddle

Comment: Fixed the fiddle, forgot to save it.  I'll update in a minute.

Comment: Added an example (probably not perfect) of using a function to do the work for you.  As long as you keep the naming convention the same, should be able to add as many different things as you need.

Comment: yep works in code fiddle. thanks for your time & help

Answer (score 1):

Many possible solutions. Will this work for you?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mp").click(function () {
        $("#loadingImage").toggle("slow");
        $( "#p1" ).toggle( "slow" );
        $("#loadingImage2").hide();
        $("#p2").hide();
    });
})
$("#mp2").click(function () {
        $("#loadingImage2").toggle("slow");
        $( "#p2" ).toggle( "slow" );
        $("#loadingImage").hide();
        $("#p1").hide();
        });
```

Comment: yep exactly the sort of thing im after. however is there a way that this can be done with multiple images without repeating similar code?

Comment: Did you try using Bootstrap? It has functionality similar to what you need and nice css features.

Comment: not yet i'll definitely have a look into it. thanks for your time & help